# Strategy for Sorting "Recently Online" Lists when Data Changes Continuously (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, redis

We have run into an interesting challenge when it comes to creating paged lists for a "members recently online" app view. The source of the challenge stems from paging on data that updates regularly.

When a member launches the view in the application it's easy to get a list in a given location (by most recent login order in New York for instance) with a simple call to the database. This works perfectly for the first set (page 1). However, when the member scrolls and the app requests the next set (page 2) the list may have new members added to the top of it, this causes overlaps between result set 1 and 2 and so on.

To complicate things a little more, we want to store accountID's from the results in Redis to prevent unnecessary duplicate MySQL queries hitting the DB and helps speed things up.

We considered using timestamps as a starting point. This strategy gives us a set point in time ensuring our list is always returned in order until the members does a pull to refresh list. The problem with this solution though means the DB gets hit every time and Redis can't be used effectively.

Furthermore, a member may have their app on the "recently online" view, leave the app and come back 30 minutes later and continue scrolling from where they were which will surely lead to unexpected results.

Does anyone have a good solution or strategy that solves this kind of a problem without creating a wonky user experience and unnecessary taxation on server resources?

Comment: Talking meta-ish, I'd say, if you get a good answer, the same solution should also be applied to the paging operation of SO on tagged questions - clicking on the second page may only "half-scroll", if new questions came in in the meantime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have landed on strategy to handle this challenge that solves most of what we are trying to accomplish. To solve this problem we are implementing the following.

When a member requests "Who's Recently Online" We generate a list of local members capped to 150 accounts. The entire list is passed to the app in a comma delimited string of member ID's so that the app has a set of records that it can page through. This solves the problem of relying on the API to have knowledge of where a member is in a list at any given time.

With the initial request we also include the member information for the first 15 most recently logged in accounts so that the screen can populate without having to make a second call to the API. Since we have passed a complete snapshot of the online now list, the app can request the next set of 15 accounts by passing their ID's to our API to return those account details.

When the member does a pull to refresh or leaves the list and returns to it after moving to another area of the app, the process starts all over again.

This is how we have been able to solve the paging problem. Essentially give the app a snapshot in time and let it page through that snapshot until it's time to update/renew the list.